# How to Get User's Friendly Display Name on SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, aspx

I have been searching around the web trying to find some help on this.
We are working on a aspx page hosted on a Sharepoint2010 site.
We have been able to successfully get the current logged in user's username in the format of "DomainName\UserName" - by using the below very basic code:

```
<asp:LoginName id="LoginName01" runat="server" FormatString={0}/>
```

Need help in getting the friendly display name of the user - "FirstName LastName" - of the current logged in user.

Comment: On SharePoint 2013, it's even worse since you get the extra 'i:0#.w' which added by the `claims authentication`. I'd recommend NOT to use string split, and instead to use `SPClaimProviderManager.Local.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following with Sharepoint designer

1- Add  inside  as

```
 <ParameterBindings>
    <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="EF49CFE7-C6C4-42D6-8FCB-B10D6CDC0A35"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location="ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)"/>
</ParameterBindings>
```

2- Add `<xsl:param name="LogonUser"/>` before template  `<xsl:template match="/">`

3- You can get the value of current login as  `<xsl:value-of select="$LogonUser"/>` inside your template

Another method using SPServices

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
  webURL: "",       // Added in 2013.01
  fieldName: "Name",
  fieldNames: {},       // Added in v0.7.2 to allow multiple columns
  debug: false
});
```

link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88c1d5e6-649f-4b97-91b3-07b2093fb931/get-current-login-user-in-sharepoint-desginer-codebehind?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious

http://yalla.itgroove.net/2011/12/02/sharepoint-2010-get-current-username-logged-in-user/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this SharePoint specific code

```
<%= SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name %>
```

It should get you the users display name

Comment: I tried to put this into the ASPX page and it was still not pulling any - I literally copy-pasted the code you provided into the body of the HTML in between the <span> tag. Could be that am using it wrongly.
Could you please help me with small example to how and where in the page i can use it to display the Display Name of the current logged in user.